# 2D list has weird behavor when trying to modify a single value

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

When I try this code:

```
data = [[None]*5]*5
data[0][0] = 'Cell A1'
```

The value of `data` ends up like:

```
[['Cell A1', None, None, None, None],
 ['Cell A1', None, None, None, None],
 ['Cell A1', None, None, None, None],
 ['Cell A1', None, None, None, None],
 ['Cell A1', None, None, None, None]]
```

Why does the `'Cell A1'` value appear in every nested list?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This makes a list with five references to the **same** list:

```
data = [[None]*5]*5
```

Use something like this instead which creates five separate lists:

```
>>> data = [[None]*5 for _ in range(5)]
```

Now it behaves as expected:

```
>>> data[0][0] = 'Cell A1'
>>> print(data)
[['Cell A1', None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 21):

As explained in the [documentation for sequence types](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) (which includes lists):

> Note also that the copies are shallow; nested structures are not copied. This often haunts new Python programmers; consider:
>
> ```
> >>> lists = [[]] * 3
> >>> lists
> [[], [], []]
> >>> lists[0].append(3)
> >>> lists
> [[3], [3], [3]]
> ```
>
> What has happened is that `[[]]` is a one-element list containing an empty list, so all three elements of `[[]] * 3` are (pointers to) this single empty list. Modifying any of the elements of `lists` modifies this single list. You can create a list of different lists this way:
>
> ```
> >>> lists = [[] for i in range(3)]  
> >>> lists[0].append(3)
> >>> lists[1].append(5)
> >>> lists[2].append(7)
> >>> lists
> [[3], [5], [7]]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, every variable is an object, and thus a reference. You first created a list of 5 `None`s, and then you build a list with 5 times the same object.