# python list comprehension: creating 2d array

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python 2D list has weird behavor when trying to modify a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739552/python-2d-list-has-weird-behavor-when-trying-to-modify-a-single-value)

folks,

I am wondering if the two following statements are the same?

```
a = [[0]*3]*3
b = [[0]*3 for i in range(3)]
```

The results look the same. But would one way be better than the other? What is the difference here.

Thanks very much for your help.

nos

Comment: There are literally thousands questions covering this exact topic...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're not the same

```
>>> a[1][2] = 5
>>> a
>>> [[0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 5]]


>>> b[1][2] = 5
>>> b
>>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0]]
```

The first one creates an outer array of pointers to a single inner array while the second actually creates 3 separate arrays.

Comment: I was typing the *exact* same thing.  +1 to you.

Comment: yup, in the first one, all three arrays are the same object. If you use integers instead for example [1]*5 instead of [[]]*5, a new integer is used in each position

Comment: these are not python arrays...these are python lists.

Answer (score 7):

No they are not.
In the first one you have (a list of) 3 identical lists, same reference, in the second you have three different lists

```
>>> a = [[0]*3]*3
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]=1

>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]


>>> b = [[0]*3 for i in range(3)]
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> b[0][0] = 1

>>> b
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: +1. Try `a[0].append("foo")`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic case of shallow-copy vs deep copy, as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) in the Python docs :)