# Python list of list syntax

Tags: python, list, syntax

What is the difference between these two declarations of a list of lists?

```
>>> l = [[]]*4
>>> l
[[], [], [], []]
>>> l[1].append(1)
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]

>>> m = [[],[],[],[]]
>>> m[1].append(1)
>>> m
[[], [1], [], []]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2D list has weird behavor when trying to modify a single value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739552/python-2d-list-has-weird-behavor-when-trying-to-modify-a-single-value)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one creates four references to a single list --- it is the same list repeated four times.  The second creates four distinct lists.  In the first case, when you append to one list, it affects all of them, because they are all the same object.  In the second case, each list is a distinct object, so appending to one doesn't affect the others.

Answer (score 4):

this will give you a clear idea, in `l` all object have the same `id()` and all are mutable so editing any one of them will automatically edit other too, as they all are just refernces to a same object with `id=18671936`  and in `m` all have different `id()`, so all of them are different objects.

```
>>> l = [[]]*4
>>> for x in l:
        print(id(x))

18671936 
18671936
18671936
18671936

>>> m=[[],[],[],[]]
>>> for x in m:
        print(id(x))

10022256
18671256
18672496
18631696
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help make it more explicit? This is equivalent to your first example:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = [l1]*4
>>> l2
[[], [], [], []]
```

What you're basically doing there is creating a list with 4 items, all of which reference the same list. In my code, that list is named `l1`.

As Mark mentioned below in the comment, this is also exactly like this:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = [l1, l1, l1, l1]
>>> l2
[[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: +1.  When explaining this to others, I find it helps to go even one step further and explain that the second line above is equivalent to simply writing `l2 = [l1, l1, l1, l1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that helps me understand this phenomenon is that you need to *explicitly* construct *every* list that you want.

You can explicitly construct an empty list with `[]`. In the first example you've done that once, so you have one list. In the second you've done it four times, so there are four lists.

If you don't want to write `[]` many times you can do

```
[[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Good point. In the OP's example, number of distinct lists created == number of `[]`'s