# 2D list editing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to edit a 5 * 5 square matrix in Python.And I initialize every element in this 5 * 5 matrix with the value 0. I initialize the matrix by using lists using this code:

```
h = []
for i in range(5):
    h.append([0,0,0,0,0])
```

And now I want to change the matrix to something like this.

```
4 5 0 0 0
0 4 5 0 0 
0 0 4 5 0
0 0 0 4 5
5 0 0 0 4
```

Here is the piece of code -

```
    i = 0
    a = 0
    while i < 5:
        h[i][a] = 4
        h[i][a+1] = 5
        a += 1
        i += 1
```

where h[i][j] is the 2 D matrix. But the output is always is showing something like this -

```
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
```

Can you guys tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry man, Thnx for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

Do the update as follows using the modulo operator `%`:

```
for i in range(5):
    h[i][i % 5] = 4
    h[i][(i+1) % 5] = 5
```

The `% 5` in the first line isn't strictly necessary but underlines the general principle for matrices of various dimensions. Or more generally, for random dimensions:

```
for i, row in enumerate(h):
    n = len(row)
    row[i % n] = 4
    row[(i+1) % n] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Question answered here: [2D list has weird behavor when trying to modify a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739552/2d-list-has-weird-behavor-when-trying-to-modify-a-single-value)

This should work:

```
#m = [[0]*5]*5  # Don't do this.

m = []
for i in range(5):
    m.append([0]*5)

i = a = 0
while i < 5:
    m[i][a] = 4
    if a < 4:
        m[i][a+1] = 5
    a += 1
    i += 1
```