# Creating 2D python list with predefined length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, graph

I have a small graph [image].

I want to add nodes to a 2D list like this. [image]

`0` is connected to nodes `1` and `2`, so at index `0` these two nodes are inserted and so on. The program should take input from user. For simplification, I have written this code.

```
l = [[]]*4

l[0].append(1)
l[0].append(2)

l[1].append(0)
l[1].append(3)

l[2].append(0)
l[2].append(3)

l[3].append(1)
l[3].append(2)

print(l, end="\n")
```

But the output is
`[[1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2]]`

And I want output as in the second image. How to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739597/7421710

Comment: This should solve your problem: ```l = [[input('num') for i in range(2)] for b in range(4)]```