# Can't explain list behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on a list and do not get it - why do I get the result below:

```
    TenLast = [["."] * 10 ] * NumberOfHosts
    
    for i in range(0,NumberOfHosts):
        TenLast[i][0] = i
        
    print(TenLast)
    exit()
```

```
    [[6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

I would expect

```
    [[0, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [1, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [2, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [3, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [4, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [5, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

thank you for for help,support and any ideas.

regards,
HEP

Comment: Your sublists are all referring to the same list in memory. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739552/2d-list-has-weird-behavor-when-trying-to-modify-a-single-value)

Answer (score 2):

Your sublists are all referring to the same list in memory. You can get around this by using `itertools`.

```
import itertools
TenLast = list(itertools.repeat([["."] * 10 ],NumberOfHosts))
for i in range(0,NumberOfHosts):
    TenLast[i][0] = i
print(TenLast)
```